# Verificar se parêntese foi fechado

Tags: javascript, regex

Preciso de um Regex que verifique se dentro da *string*, o parêntese foi fechado.

Este é meu exemplo:

```
/regex/.test("fdfdfdf(ddsd");  //retorna false, porque o parentese nao foi fechado;.

/regex/.test("fdfedff(ffd)dd") //retorma true,  porque o parentese foi fechado;.
```

Minha preferência é que fosse feita como Regex, mas se for difícil ou impossível, pode ser de outra forma, porém minha exigência irredutível, é que seja em JavaScript puro.

Obs.: Isto vai ser feito em uma caixa de texto, então o número de caracteres dentro e fora do parêntese irá variar.

Comment: Não percebi qual a sua dúvida.

Comment: @Jorge B. Eu preciso de um `regex` que verifique se dentro da string, o parêntese foi fechado.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly, você poderia fazer uma demostração de como isso seria feito?

Comment: @SamirBraga, feito.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você procura por um algoritmo de balanceamento de parenteses.

Definição do algoritmo: Percorra a String caractere a caractere registrando a quantidade de parenteses abertos e a quantidade de parenteses fechados. Se, em qualquer momento `quantidade de parenteses abertos - quantidade de parenteses fechados < 0` então essa é uma expressão inválida. Se no fim da String esse saldo for positivo então existem parenteses abertos.

```
function isBalanced(s)
{
  var open = (arguments.length > 1) ? arguments[1] : '(';
  var close = (arguments.length > 2) ? arguments[2] : ')';  
  var c = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++)
  {
    var ch = s.charAt(i);
    if ( ch == open )
    {
      c++;
    }
    else if ( ch == close )
    {
      c--;
      if ( c < 0 ) return false;
    }
  }
  return c == 0;
}
```

**Fonte:** [RossetaCode.org - Balanced brackets](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Balanced_brackets#JavaScript)

---

#### UPDATE

[Exemplo funcional no Ideone](http://ideone.com/Y8v7da).

Comment: Você poderia colocar seu exemplo no `jsFiddle`, porque estou tendo uma dificuldade.

Comment: Depois de parar um pouco, consegui o resultado que queria, com o seu código.

Comment: Tranquilo. Deixei um exemplo do Ideone, parece que o jsfiddle está offline.

Comment: `parece que o jsfiddle está offline`, jeje, *e metade das publicações no [so] foram pras cucuias!*

Answer (score 6):

Se você possui um número **fixo** de parênteses (ex.: `1` e apenas `1` - não zero ou um, não um ou dois, apenas um) você pode fazer com a seguinte regex:

```
[^()]*[(][^()]*[)][^()]*
```

Caso contrário é impossível de se fazer com regex (não corresponde a uma [linguagem regular](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguagem_regular)). Veja [a resposta do Anthony Accioly](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28468/215) para uma possível solução.

Comment: Sempre tem um mago de Perl [viajando nas expressões regulares](http://stackoverflow.com/a/133771/664577), mas JS não suporta regex recursivas (ainda bem).